# Rotating/aligning texture coordinates

Tags: opengl, geometry

I have 1024x1 gradient texture that I want to map to a quad. This gradient should be aligned along the line (p1,p2) inside that quad. The texture has the GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE property, so it will fill the entire quad.

I now need to figure out the texture coordinates for the four corners (A,B,C,D) of the quad, but I can't wrap my head around the required math.

[image]

I tried to calculate the angle between (p1,p2) and then rotate the corner points around the center of the line between (p1,2), but I couldn't get this to work right. It seems a bit excessive anyway - is there an easier solution?

Comment: Why do u need a texture to apply a gradient to a quad?

Comment: I need a texture because the gradient may have more than one color stop, and has to be arbitrarily aligned. I could use a pixel shader, but this will make it a lot slower (It's an iPhone project; performance counts).

Comment: Should the gradient always be centered on the quad or should it use the center of the line?

Comment: It should be centered on the line. The picture illustrates how the texture (black rectangle from p1 to p2) may sit in the quad.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using  shaders? If yes, then assign your quad just default UVs from 0 to 1 .Then based on the p1 p2 segment slope calculate the  degrees for rotation (don't forget to convert those to radians). Then in the vertex shader construct 2x2 rotation matrix and rotate the UVs the amount defined by the segment.At the end pass the rotated UVs into fragment shader and use with your gradient texture sampler.

Comment: I'm doing the UV calculations in the application itself, but other than that this is pretty much what I was trying. I just thought there may be a simpler solution without calculating the angle etc. Anyway, I think I'm still having problems with turning p1,p2 into sensible UV coordinates somehow. I'll keep trying around, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach that actually works as I want it to, using only additions, multiplications and one div; sparing the expensive sqrt.

I first calculate the slope of the (p1,p2) line and the one orthogonal to it. I then work out the intersection points of the slope (starting at p1) and the orthogonal stating at each corner.

```
Vector2 slope = {p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y};
Vector2 ortho = {-slope.y, slope.x};

float div = 1/(slope.y * ortho.x - slope.x * ortho.y);
Vector2 A = {
    (ortho.x * -p1.y + ortho.y * p1.x) * div,
    (slope.x * -p1.y + slope.y * p1.x) * div
};
Vector2 B = {
    (ortho.x * -p1.y + ortho.y * (p1.x - 1)) * div,
    (slope.x * -p1.y + slope.y * (p1.x - 1)) * div
};
Vector2 C = {
    (ortho.x * (1 - p1.y) + ortho.y * p1.x) * div,
    (slope.x * (1 - p1.y) + slope.y * p1.x) * div
};
Vector2 D = {
    (ortho.x * (1 - p1.y) + ortho.y * (p1.x - 1)) * div,
    (slope.x * (1 - p1.y) + slope.y * (p1.x - 1)) * div
};
```